# Order cluster nodes in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I have the following (simplified) graph which is generated by the following .dot:

[image]

```
digraph Configurations {

  subgraph cluster_1 {
    s_0_0 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="0",fillcolor=yellowgreen]
    s_0_1 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="1",fillcolor=yellowgreen]
  }
  subgraph cluster_2 {
    s_1_0 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="0",fillcolor=yellowgreen]
    s_1_1 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="1",fillcolor=white]
  }
  subgraph cluster_3 {
    s_2_0 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="0",fillcolor=white]
    s_2_1 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="1",fillcolor=yellowgreen]
  }
  subgraph cluster_4 {
    s_3_0 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="0",fillcolor=white]
    s_3_1 [shape=circle,style=filled,fixedsize=true,width=0.5,label="1",fillcolor=white]
  }

  s_0_1 -> s_1_1
  s_0_0 -> s_2_0
  s_2_1 -> s_3_1
  s_1_0 -> s_3_0
}
```

I would like to be able to be able to enforce ordering inside the subgraphs so that the nodes of each subgraph are displayed in ascending order (each cluster should have nodes placed (0, 1), never (1, 0)). As I understand it, rankdir, which was my first attempt, is not supported in subgraphs, so what is a proper way to do this? I am looking for a solution which gives me a reasonably similar layout (which would then include more intersecting arrows) and is scalable, since the real graphs will be huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this could be solved by adding invisible edges inside and forcing same rank inside the graphs, like so:

```
subgraph cluster_1 {
    {rank=same; s_0_0 s_0_1}
    s_0_0 -> s_0_1 [style=invis]
    s_0_0 [shape=circle, style=filled, fixedsize=true,
        width=0.5, label="0", fillcolor=yellowgreen]
    s_0_1 [shape=circle, style=filled, fixedsize=true, 
        width=0.5, label="1", fillcolor=yellowgreen]
}
```

Comment: Used both answers and unable to realign the nodes as connections between other nodes in graph seems realign the order.

Comment: Works like a charm for me! Even with multiple nodes. Thank you!

Comment: under some circumstances with this solution, connecting nodes in different clusters can again change the ordering. you can additionally set `remincross=false` on the graph to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1):

If there are more nodes than 2 nodes, we need to change the solution.

```
subgraph cluster1 {
    {
        HL_1_n HL_1_1 HL_1_2 HL_1_3 HL_1_m
    }
    HL_1_1   [label="Hidden Layer 1 Node 1" color=3]
    HL_1_2   [label="Hidden Layer 1 Node 2" color=3]
    HL_1_3   [label="Hidden Layer 1 Node 3" color=3]
    HL_1_m   [label="Hidden Layer 1 Node ..." color=3]
    HL_1_n   [label="Hidden Layer 1 Node H_1" color=3]
    label = "Hidden Layer"
}
```

It seems the order is determined, so we just need to change nodes' positions to fit the output. The solution does not use edge constraints and rank.